# php Email users in database

Tags: php, email, pdo

I am trying to send an email to selected users from my database. I do a select query and then use the results of email addresses to send mail the them.

Code:

```
 foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $result) 
{
    $mail = $result['email'];


    //Email information

  $to_email = "$mail";
  $from_email = "myemail@mysite.com";
  $subject = "Subject";
  $comment =  "Content"
  mail($to_email, "$subject", $comment, "From: Website <" . $from_email . ">");
}
```

It works, but send multiple emails to each user. For eg. If there are 10 users selected, each user receives 10 emails. I know that is because the `foreach`, I have also tried with `while`. But I do not know how to fix.

Comment: create array of email_address and pass that array as $to_email and use mail function outside loop

Comment: Can you show a bit more code? Perhaps you're looping the resultset multiple times?

Comment: how each user will receives 10 emails?

Comment: I hope it's not *too* many users (i.e. not a mass mailing list) - looping `mail()` isn't efficient so you might need to look into IMAP or, if the list is big enough, a third party mailing solution.

Comment: shouldn´t in be a  foreach($stmt->fetch() as $result) instead fetchall ?

Comment: @FatFreddy No, you do a `foreach` over all records or you fetch each one individualy using a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php) works. It gets you a result-array with all lines from your query. So if you use `foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $result)` you will loop multiple times over all your results. You need to fetch all results and then loop over them.

```
$results = $stmt > fetchAll ();
foreach (results as $result) {
...
}
```

Or use [fetch()](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php) in your loop.

```
while (($result = $stmt -> fetch ()) !== false) {
...
}
```